# Android Relative Paths to Fonts From CSS File

Tags: android, html, css, webview, assets

I have some custom in-page css styling I am applying to webpages I load into my webview. I want to use custom fonts, referenced as so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
    src: url(...);
}
```

Currently, the fonts are stored in the assets folder (sibling to res), and the html pages are fetched online and loaded into the webview view via `loadDataWithBaseURL` as so: `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(CONSTANTS.BASE_URL, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);` Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Easier than I thought. Here is the solution:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
    src: url(file:///android_asset/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf);
}
```

Comment: Haha nice, Thank you for your help friend :)

Answer (score 1):

If your font file is `OpenSans-Light.ttf` and it's stored in `assets/fonts/`, then the following would work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf');
}
```